# how can I install nvidia drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

i have a laptop with Ubuntu 13.10 GNOME in it. GNOME Shell version is 3.10.1.
Here's what I got from running the following command:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor
Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)    
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce 610M] (rev a1).
```

In the Additional Drivers pane, I have listed just my wifi card driver. How can I install Nvidia drivers without bumblebee and via ppa?
I'm really confused about this. I would like to install the 319.17 drivers, which are the stable version for my graphics card. I don't know what to install (nvidia, nvidia-current, nvidia graphic 319, etc.)
could you tell me what I have to do to install nvidia 319,17 (or just 319) via ppa and without bumblebee, please!

I tried going to *System Settings* -> *Software & Updates* -> *Additional Drivers* to check for additional Nvidia drivers, but there weren't any Nvidia drivers in the list in the Additional Drivers tab. However when I checked in the Ubuntu Software Center, there were several different nvidia packages there, as shown in this screenshot: http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/6374/8w0l.png

I have already tried to install the nvidia-319 package from the Ubuntu Software Center, but after reboot Ubuntu did not load correctly. I could only see the mark of Ubuntu GNOME and nothing else, the desktop or GNOME Shell didn't even load. I also couldn't go to the login page. Then I removed the nvidia-319 package, and now I have my system back. Through all of this I have been using the default gdm package for the login screen display manager application.

I still don't know what Nvidia package to install and how to get the proprietary Nvidia graphics package to work on my system. Please help i don't know what to do. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*It has easy steps*

You just have to download the  NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce 610M] drivers.

## follow these steps.

go to http://www.nvidia.in/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-in
download the required drivers for your system.

then the downloaded file will be saved in Downloads folder.

now you have the required drivers so you have to install them on your system.

so reboot your system.and immediately when ubuntu boots, press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>

this will allow you to switch to runlevel.i.e. command line interface

login to your account

then go to the downloads directory by using command *cd Downloads*

now issue the command

*chmod 777 "your drivers file name"*

*./"drivers file name"*

it will prompt that you need to stop x-server
so type this command

*sudo service lightdm stop*

it will stop the display manager for ubuntu.and now you have to use the above command

*./"drivers file name"*

now follow the installation steps by selecting yes option.
finally your nvidia drivers will be installed on yoor system.

hope that works for you,regards.

Comment: i tried this, but i had some errors that failed the installation such as: "the distribution-provided pre-install script failed" and "failed to run "/usr/sbin/dkms ...." and "unable to build the modul installation, ecc..